# Detect position of a ListViewItem in ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, windows-10

I have a ListView control that is rendering a UserControl within. I want to be able to tell which items are showing in the current view i.e. everything that's showing in the current view to the user.

As an example:

```
        _______________
        |             |
|1| |2| | |3| |4| |5| | |6| |7|
        |_____________|
```

Here I'd want to know that 3, 4 and 5 are presented to the user and that, 1, 2, 6 and 7 are outside the visible area.

How does one accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juts set the attached property of the `ScrollViewer` `CanContentScroll` to `True` in your `ListView`, to make sure that the `ScrollViewer` is scrolled in terms of physical units not logical ones (there no half items shown in the `ListView` ViewPort for example), then handle the `ScrollChanged` event to get the unit offset each time :

```
 <ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" x:Name="Lv" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="Lv_OnScrollChanged" Height="100">

        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 1" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 2" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 3" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 4" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 5" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 6" />
        <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                Content="Item 7" />

    </ListView>
```

Make sure that the `ListView` height (or width, if you want to use a horizontal ListView ) must be a multiplier of the ListViewItem height (above *100=x*50, x ∈ ℕ*).

The visible `ListViewItems` are deduced from the `VerticalOffset` in the event handler:

```
private void Lv_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var verticalOffet=e.VerticalOffset;
        //the visible items are the items number from verticalOffet until verticalOffet+(ListView Heigh/ListViewItem Height) 
    }
```

for example if the event is fired and the verticalOffet is **2**, then the visible items in the `ListView` ViewPort are Item 3, and Item 4.